# Failed to install Android SDK Tools, and want to install KVM for Android Studio

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, android-studio

i know my Question is probably divergent and maybe looks like other questions but i just can't figure it out on my own :(
bear with me :D

my computer:

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Android Studio version 3.4 installed by Ubuntu software

java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)

Question:
How to resolve this error ? what should i do with the KVM installation ?

I installed android studio from Ubuntu software, after couple of weeks tried to run it and got me into some downloads required mentioned in the first picture

[image]

then i head to this page 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

to install KVM checked every thing as mentioned in the website and installed everything till this "Lucid (10.04) or later"
then instead of completing the instructions i clicked finish in the suspended Android Studio installation and it asked me to install Android SDK Tools and i got this error.

[image]

error messege:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 
'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/
emulator-linux-5395263.zip': 
Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Android Emulator: Cannot download 
'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/
emulator-linux-5395263.zip': 
Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Android SDK Platform 28: dl.google.com.

java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Android SDK Platform-Tools: dl.google.com.

java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Sources for Android 28: dl.google.com.

java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3: 
dl.google.com.
java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK 
package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: 
dl.google.com.
```

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance :D